# MongoDB: find field's value according to 2 collection

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I'm using MongoDB, and I have two collections like below:

Person:

```
{  
   "name":"Bob",
   "info":{  
      "birthplace":[  
         "Paris, France"
      ],
      "birthdate":[  
         "18 June 1961"
      ]
   }
}
```

City:

```
{  
   name:"Paris",
   country:"FR",
   population:8022,
   location:{  
      longitude:42.46372,
      latitude:1.49129
   }
}
```

For each person whose birthplace is known, I want to find the location and population of that city. I looked up the documents and find that we can use `$lookup`to aggregate, like below:

```
Person.orders.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup:
        {
          from: "City",
          localField: "birthplace",
          foreignField: "name",
          as: "inventory_docs"
        }
   }
])
```

But the problem is that the value of `City.name`is contained in `Person.birthplace`, so they can't match, any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your $lookup will work if you $unwind **"$info.birthplace"** first:

```
Person.orders.aggregate([{$unwind: "$info.birthplace"},
                         {$lookup: {from: "city",
                                    localField: "info.birthplace",
                                    foreignField: "name",
                                    as: "inventory_docs"}
                         }]);
```

And **"$info.birthplace"** must really match the **"name"** from the city (now it does not, "Paris, France" is not equal to "Paris").

Besides that, it is not clear why **"info.birthplace"** and **"info.birthdate"** in the person document are arrays. It seems to have no meaning as a person can not have more than one birth date and place.